# How to clone a NSDictionary to JavaScript object [iOS Cordova Cross-Platform]

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays, cordova, webview

Dear fellow programmers,

I have to finish one project and I am that close to finishing it but I am not able to figure how to do it. Maybe somebody here will be able to help me.

I work on a simple iOS app using Cordova in which I have to load several jSONs through Objective-C and I have to be able to use that data inside the WebView. The data of each jSON are loaded in NSDictionary respectively, so when I NSLog it, I get for example:

```
    data =     (
            {
        "id_string" = TRAVELLING;
        name = Traveling;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = FOOD;
        name = Food;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = FASHION;
        name = Fashion;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = RELAX;
        name = Relax;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = FUN;
        name = Fun;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = CHILDREN;
        name = "For children";
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = GIFTS;
        name = Gifts;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = STOCK;
        name = Stock;
        sequence = 0;
    },
            {
        "id_string" = OTHER;
        name = Other;
        sequence = 0;
    }
);
"request_duration" = "0.017858028411865";
status = success;
}
```

Now I know there is a way how to inject data from Objective-C to JavaScript inside the WebView and that is by creating JavaScript function, which will handle the Object creation and which will be called from Objective-C together with needed parameters via

```
NSString *cText     = @"This is a text from Objective-C";
NSString *cFullText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"receiveMessage('%@')", cText];
NSString *cResult   = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:cFullText];
```

where receiveMessage is a Javascript function.

The goal is to rebuild a JavaScript Object that when echoed through Console.Log would look like this:

```
.   [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
.   0: Object
.   id_string: “TRAVELLING”
.   name : “Traveling”
.   sequence: 0
.   __proto__: Object
.   1: Object
.   id_string: “FOOD”
.   name : “Food”
.   sequence: 0
.   __proto__: Object
.   2: Object
.   3: Object
.   4: Object
.   5: Object
.   6: Object
.   7: Object
.   8: Object
```

so that I would be able to retrieve a value by:

```
firstIDString = categoriesArray[0].id_string;
firstName     = categoriesArray[0].name;
```

With that in mind, I am trying the following:

I. create a foreach loop for NSDictionary, that would rebuild the Object line by line [okay but not perfect in my opinion]

or

II. stringily the received jSON in Objective-C, send it through the JavaScript function once and rebuild it with slice or something similar. [better in my opinion]

Currently I am testing the first approach (thinking that the second one would be much better, not being sure how I should execute it) via:

```
function appendArrayWithDataFromObjeciveC(arrayName,id,keyName,value){


  //arrayName[id] = [];
  //arrayName[id][keyName] = value;
  //arrayName.push( { ID:1, "Name":"whatever" } );
  //arrayName[ id ].keyName = value;
  //arrayName[keyName] = value;

  console.log("Array before:");
  console.log(arrayName);

  var tempArray = [];
  tempArray = {keyName : value};

  arrayName = arrayName.concat(tempArray);

  console.log("Array after:");
  console.log(arrayName);
  return "OK";

}
```

While this creates an Array with added information once, I am not sure how to advance the ID (object length) so that I am not always rewriting the 0 index.

Do you guys have any suggestions how to accomplish this?
Thank you for your time and input.